# When more than one semantic ui modal is opened, the first opened modal does not close

Tags: jquery, tabs, semantic-ui

When more than one semantic ui modal is opened, the first opened modal does not close

my first mod will open
#shareModal Code

```html
<div class="ui modal test" id="share-modal">
    <i class="close icon modalCloseIcon"></i>
    <div class="header">
        <span class="textWhiteSpace">test</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="ui grid">
            <div class="seven wide computer sixteen wide tablet column">
                <div class="ui form">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label id="add-user-group">@lang.AddPersonOrGroup</label>
                        <select class="mySelect2" multiple data-role="none"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline field">
                        <label><h5 class="ui left floated header">Yetki</h5></label><div class="ui grid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="eight wide column">
                                    <div role="list" class="ui list">
                                        <div role="listitem" class="item">
                                            <div class="ui checked disabled checkbox"><input class="main-item" disabled="" name="List" readonly="" tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" value="0" checked="checked"><label>@Language.lang.List</label></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div role="listitem" class="item"><div class="ui checked checkbox"><input class="main-item" name="View" readonly="" tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" value="1"><label>@lang.View</label></div></div>
                                        <div role="listitem" class="item"><div class="ui checkbox"><input class="main-item" name="Read" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="2"><label>@lang.Read</label></div></div>
                                        <div role="listitem" class="item"><div class="ui checkbox"><input class="main-item" name="Change" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="3"><label>@lang.Change</label></div></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="eight wide column">
                                    <div role="list" class="ui list">
                                        <div role="listitem" class="item">
                                            <div class="ui checkbox">
                                                <input class="main-item" name="Share" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="4"><label>@lang.Share</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div role="listitem" class="item"><div class="ui checkbox"><input class="main-item" name="Link" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="5"><label>@lang.Link</label></div></div>
                                        <div role="listitem" class="item"><a onclick="ShowOrHideOptions()" id="custom-options">@lang.ShowAdvanced</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" id="advanced-features" style="display:none;">
                                
                                <div role="list" class="ui column" style="column-count:2; padding:0px 0px 25px 15px; line-height:1.6em;">
                                    <div role="listitem" class="item">
                                        <div class="ui checked disabled checkbox">
                                            <input class="specific" disabled name="List" id="specific" readonly="" tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked"><label>@Language.lang.List</label>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-create-folder">
                                        <div class="ui checkbox">
                                            <input class="specific" name="CreateFolder" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="2">
                                            <label>@lang.CreateFolder</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-create-file">
                                        <div class="ui checkbox">
                                            <input class="specific" name="CreateFile" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="4">
                                            <label>@lang.CreateFile</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-delete">
                                        <div class="ui checkbox">
                                            <input class="specific" name="Delete" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="8">
                                            <label>@lang.Delete</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-download">
                                        <div class="ui checkbox">
                                            <input class="specific" name="Download" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="16">
                                            <label>@lang.Download</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-upload">
                                        <div class="ui checkbox">
                                            <input class="specific" name="Upload" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="32">
                                            <label>@lang.Upload</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-share">
                                        <div class="ui checked checkbox">
                                            <input class="specific" name="Share" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="64">
                                            <label>@lang.Share</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-link">
                                        <div class="ui checkbox">
                                            <input class="specific" name="Link" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="128">
                                            <label>@lang.Link</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-rename">
                                        <div class="ui checkbox">
                                            <input class="specific" name="Rename" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="256">
                                            <label>@lang.Rename</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-view">
                                        <div class="ui checked checkbox">
                                            <input class="specific" name="View" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="512">
                                            <label>@lang.View</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-move"><div class="ui checkbox"><input class="specific" name="Move" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="1024"><label>@lang.Move</label></div></div>
                                    <div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-copy">
                                        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="specific" name="Copy" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="2048"><label>@lang.Copy</label></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-edit">
                                        <div class="ui checkbox">
                                            <input class="specific" name="Edit" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="4096"><label>@lang.Edit</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-document-edit">
                                        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="specific" name="DocumentEdit" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="8192"><label>@lang.DocumentEdit</label></div>
                                    </div><div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-open-with-desktop">
                                        <div class="ui checkbox"><input class="specific" name="OpenWithDesktop" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="16384"><label>@lang.OpenWithDesktop</label></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-archive-operation"><div class="ui checkbox"><input class="specific" name="ArchiveOperation" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="32768"><label>@lang.ArchiveOperation</label></div></div>
                                    <div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-note"><div class="ui checkbox"><input class="specific" name="Note" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="65536"><label>@lang.Note</label></div></div>
                                    <div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-user-label"><div class="ui checkbox"><input class="specific" name="UserLabel" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="131072"><label>@lang.UserLabel</label></div></div>
                                    <div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-favorite"><div class="ui checkbox"><input class="specific" name="Favorite" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="262144"><label>@lang.Favorite</label></div></div>
                                    <div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-lock">
                                        <div class="ui checkbox">
                                            <input class="specific" name="Lock" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="524288">
                                            <label>@lang.Lock</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div role="listitem" class="item" id="auth-version">
                                        <div class="ui checkbox">
                                            <input class="specific" name="Version" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="checkbox" value="1048576">
                                            <label>@lang.Version</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field ui clearing divider"></div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <h5 class="ui left floated header">
                            @lang.AddExpirationDate
                            <i class="description small link blue small info circle icon show-content" id="description-link-expirationdate" data-content="@lang.DescriptionLinkExpirationDate"></i>
                        </h5>

                    </div>
                    <div class="expiration-date container" id="expiration-date-container">
                        <div class="expiration-time field">
                            <div class="ui selection dropdown expiration-time" id="expiration-time-dropdown">
                                <input name="linkDuration" type="hidden" value="null">

                                <div class="text" value="null">Never expires</div>
                                <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                                <div class="menu">
                                    <div class="item" value="null" data-value="null">Never expires</div>
                                    <div class="item" value="1" data-value="1">1 @lang.Day  @lang.Later</div>
                                    <div class="item" value="7" data-value="7">1 @lang.Week @lang.Later</div>
                                    <div class="item" value="30" data-value="30">1 @lang.Month @lang.Later</div>
                                    <div class="item" value="0" data-value="0">@lang.CustomDate</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="field" id="share-date-details"  style="display: none; padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;">
                            <div class="ui two column grid">
                                <div class="eight wide computer sixteen wide mobile eight wide tablet column">
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label>Date:</label>
                                        <div class="field expiration-time date exdate modal-date" id="expiration-time-date">
                                            <div class="ui left icon input" style="width: 100%;">
                                                <i aria-hidden="true" class="calendar alternate icon"></i>
                                                <input placeholder="Date" type="text" tabindex="0" id="exp-date" class="exp-date-class" value="December 16, 2021">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="eight wide computer sixteen wide mobile eight wide tablet column">
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label>Hour:</label><div class="field expiration-time modal-hour" id="expiration-time-hour">
                                            <div localization="en" class="ui left icon input" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <i aria-hidden="true" class="time alternate icon"></i>
                                        <input placeholder="Time" type="text" tabindex="0" value="" class="exp-hour" id="exp-hour"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     
                    </div>

                    <div class="inline field"><button class="ui blue right button share" id="share" tabindex="-1">@lang.Share</button></div>


                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nine wide computer sixteen wide tablet  column">
                <label style="display:inline-block;">@lang.SharedPeopleAndGroups</label>

                <div id="waiting">

                </div>


                <div id="newTable"></div>





                <table class="ui table" style="border:none;" id="no-content">

                    <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="eight wide" style="left:-7px; position:relative; text-align: center;">
                                <i class="fa fa-share-alt" style="font-size: 25px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>


                            </td>



                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">@lang.NotShared</td>
                        </tr>



                    </tbody>

                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">

        <div id="positiveClose" class="ui positive right labeled icon button" style="background-color: #E0E1E2; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); ">
            @lang.Close
            <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
  $('#share-modal').modal('show');
```

I open the second modal like this, no problem

```
  $(".popup-modal").modal({
        allowMultiple: true
    }).modal('show');
```

I created tab in 2nd modal

```html
<div class="ui custom popup popup-modal" style="min-width: 500px; position:absolute; max-width: 550px; ">
    <div class="ui segment">

        <div class="ui stackable one column grid">
            <div class="column">
                <div role="list" class="ui divided relaxed list">
                    <div role="listitem" class="item" style="padding-bottom: 1.42857em;">
                        <div class="content"><div class="header" id="popup-authority-fullname"> </div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div role="listitem" class="item" style="padding-bottom: 1.42857em;">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="header">Authority</div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="ui  grid">
                                <div role="list" class="ui tiny container list" id="popup-modal-authority-list" style="column-count: 2;">
<div role="listitem" class="item authority-liste"><i aria-hidden="true" class="check icon"></i><div class="content">List</div></div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div role="listitem" class="item">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="header">Sharing Time</div><div id="popup-authority-sharing-time">Expires on</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).on("click", '.item', function () {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $.tab('change tab', $(this).data("tab"));

        var datatab = $(this).data("tab");
        var approvementtab = $(".approvement-tab[data-tab=" + datatab + "]").addClass("active");


    });
```

I navigated between tabs.
I closed the second modal, no problem
then i pressed the first modal close button
but first modal not closed

Comment: Please add the HTML code associated with this to be able to help you.

Comment: i added html code